# Static versus relative positioning in CSS

Tags: html, css, positioning

`Relative` positioning is the same as the default `static` positioning, except you can use offset values (top, left, etc.).

`Relative` seems objectively more powerful that `static` positioning.

Is there any disadvantage to resetting in CSS all elements to be `relative` (and overriding for `absolute` as required)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute positioned elements are relative to the closest relative container. If you set everything to relative then it will be a PITA to use absolute positioning in cases where you want your absolute element to be positioned relative to an ancestor further up the tree, because the parent of the absolute element will always be relative.

Comment: Absolute positioning, absolute positioning, absolute element, absolute element... so what about relative and static positioning? You seem to be ranting more than trying to answer the question at hand.

Comment: Huh? How am I ranting? The question is whether there is a disadvantage, and I'm clearly pointing out such a disadvantage, am I not? And what do you mean what about relative and static positioning? What are you trying to ask?

Comment: idk, this roughly shows a good case for avoiding the use of mass relative positioning.

Comment: Chosen as the answer as it identifies the disadvantage explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Relative positioning establishes a new context for absolutely positioned descendants (which are positioned with the respect to the edges of their closest ancestor that is not statically positioned).